# Using PHP's mktime() on fixed date

Tags: php, mktime

So I understand how to use `mktime()` to create a date based on the current date/time:

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")+1`

This creates a date exactly one year from now.

But how would I do this if I wanted to find out the date one year ahead of some fixed date? e.g. what will the date be 1 year in the future of the date `2017-10-01 23:59:59`

Comment: This looks like a super hack way of doing it since you're creating a half dozen dates and mashing them into the C-style `mktime` function. Why not use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) which has [manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DateTime class. Nevertheless, this answer your question:

```
$time = strtotime('27-07-2017');
$date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime( date('H', $time), date('i', $time), date('s', $time), date('m', $time), date('d', $time), date('Y', $time)+1 ) );
```